# phonegap / cordova: running 2nd javascript thread as a plugin

Tags: cordova

I'm developing a phonegap application for android. I have a database service, written in javascript that keeps the application in sync with a remote server.

I would like to run this service on a different thread, so that the processing of the data doesn't interfere with the other stuff going on in the app. It just needs to happen in the background.

I'm wondering if I could write a phonegap plugin which launches another webCore, which just runs this service.

Anyone have any ideas about how / whether this could be done?

Comment: Hey @vandervault, Did you find any answer for this issue?

Comment: what about web worker? `http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp` did you try it?

Comment: @oak, No I'd never heard of them. That looks fantastic. I won't be able to look into this for a while but will post back any outcome of giving it a go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just so happens that in the [Phonegap documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_plugin-development_android_index.md.html), there is a writeup on "How to develop a plugin" doing exactly what you asked. I'm not very fluent with Phonegap Android development, but I believe the link above should help you get on the right foot...

Edit: Since OP is also looking for how to add a second webview, I figured I'd add it to the answer.

**Yes, It's possible to add multiple webviews**

This is done by using Cordova/PhoneGap as a component with the object known as Cleaver. More documentation on how to do it can be found [here for Android](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/guide_cordova-webview_android.md.html#Embedding%20Cordova%20WebView%20on%20Android), and [here for IOS](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/guide_cordova-webview_ios.md.html#Embedding%20Cordova%20WebView%20on%20iOS).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't think the plugin guide does not say how to create a seccond webview. It's for running native code which can be called from within phonegap. My question is how does one run a webview as native code

Comment: @ddouglascarr check my edit for an answer to that question. As to running native code in a webview, you will have to use a plugin for it (those serve as links between your HTML/JS, and the native platform).